# windows 7 not allowing to install windows xp?

Tags: windows-7

I am not able to install windows xp over windows 7 and not finding any solution for that!

I do have windows xp bootable cd but it is not getting recognized as a bootable device even I have made by BIOS setting to take cd as the first bootable device, this all was working well when I did not have windows 7 installed, it used to recognize the same cd and used to boot my system from it.

Any help would really be appreciable! I really want to install one more operating system which will be windows xp to the another drive other than one in which windows 7 is installed.

Thanks,

Comment: if it really was a bootable disk then it would boot off the disk.

Comment: @David that not always true, my vista pre-installed laptop refused too boot XP but my vista pre-installed desktop would allow me to boot the same disc.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried easybcd ?

download link: http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1

you can even install MAC on your windows7